# Keep div height in line with text that has been rotated

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a heading inside it that has been transformed with CSS to be rotated -90 degrees so it appears vertically.

```
#mydiv h2 {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

The problem is that the containing div doesn't stretch with the text; instead, the text floats outside the div box.

How can I make the div stretch with the text?

Comment: Maybe the behaviour was different in 2012, but nowadays, `writing-mode: tb-rl` with `*-transform: rotate(-90deg)` results in the two cancelling each other out and the text being written horizontally. The CSS given here (and in the accepted answer below) fails to rotate the text in a modern browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `width: auto;` and `transform-origin`, but on the containing `div` - like this:

```
div {
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    outline: solid 2px green;
    width:auto;
    height:20px;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: -5px;
    background: pink;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://dabblet.com/gist/2725392
Hope this helps!

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Does it work like this? With this newer version, if I keep adding text inside the h2 tags, both the h2 and the div stretch...

Comment: -1; besides the fact that this doesn't work in modern versions of Chrome (perhaps it did in 2012!), you're just shifting the problem up one element in the hierarchy. Okay, so you can rotate the h2's parent instead of the h2; now, how do you make the *parent's parent* grow in height to contain them?

Comment: @MarkAmery To be fair, it's not Ana's fault that Chrome breaks stuff with every update. Also, it still works fine in Firefox 57.

Answer (score 1):

For an approach with `transform`, see this answer of mine to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860039/1709587

Alternatively, *just* using `writing-mode: vertical-lr` (or the deprecated `writing-mode: td-lr`) seems to work fine in modern versions of Chrome; the containing div will correctly accomodate the h2 within it, and no `transform`s are needed. See the example below:

```css
#container {
  /* Pink background for easier visualisation of the end result */
  background: pink;
  
  /* Optional; shrinks width of div to minimum required to contain h2 */
  display: inline-block;
}

#container h2 {
  /* Note that the td-lr value used in the question is deprecated;
     vertical-lr is the modern equivalent. See:
     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

     Consider also using
       -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr
     and
       -ms-writing-mode: td-lr
     for compatibility with older browsers. */
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;

  /* Optional; flips the heading, so that it is written bottom-to-top
     instead of top-to-bottom.
     Consider also using -webkit-transform and -moz-transform and
     -o-transform and an equivalent transform with filter for compatibility
     with old browsers.*/
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
  
  /* Optional: disable breaks in the title */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Some text</h2>
</div>
<div>
  More stuff
</div>
```

However, you'll find a slew of layout bugs if you try to get this working on current (December 2017) versions of Firefox, Edge, or Safari; the four major browsers have fairly broken handling of vertical `writing-mode`s at the moment. They're not consistent with each other, and they're frequently not even deterministic - you can toggle a style rule off and on again at the dev tools and end up with a differently laid-out page. As such, while this approach is an option, beware using it and test extensively if you do.

Answer (score -1):

You have to target the div size and not the h2 size add the below code and check.

```
#block-views-archive-block {
height: 20px;
width:20px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thats not right, the height of the containing div depends on how many characters in the h2 title, so the containing div must be an auto

Answer (score -1):

What if you just transformed the div instead of the text,  believe by doing that, it will also transform the div's contents.

you could also set the `height` to `auto`.

or you could just try increasing the `height` manually by adding the necessary amount of pixels.

I hope one of these solutions works!

-Brian