# Display an image in its different orientation without javascript, but only html and css

Tags: html, css, image

I have a cheque image to display which is in the landscape orientation (horizontally), but need to be displayed in the portrait orientation (vertically). But the web site has requirements of not supporting JavaScript.

For example, the below one, if I apply rotate transform, the image will turn 90 degrees clockwise and display in the portrait orientation as I wish, but it also doesn't fit in its parent DIV anymore. **How can I fix this?**

```html
<div style='border:1px solid red;'>
  DIV 1
</div>
<div style='border:1px solid red;'>
  An
  <img src="http://www.outreachaz.com/images/EMD%20Check.jpg" />image!
</div>
<div style='width:100%; border:1px solid red;'>
  DIV 2
</div>
```

```css
.rotate90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div style='border:1px solid red; margin-top:100px'>
  DIV 1
</div>
<div style='border:1px solid red;'>
  An
  <img class='rotate90' src="http://www.outreachaz.com/images/EMD%20Check.jpg" />image!
</div>
<div style='width:100%; border:1px solid red;'>
  DIV 2
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt quite understand. You mean [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/spsm6rkk/)

Comment: @TheUknown something like this effect, but assume you don't know the size of your image beforehand, so you cannot just give it top margin of 80px. I've updated my snippet. Hopefully this explains.

Comment: I found the CSS property `image-orientation` solves this perfectly, i.e.,
`.rotate90 {
  image-orientation: 90deg 
}`. But only mozilla's firefox supports it :(

Comment: That doesn't seem like a viable option then. Leaves only a couple of lines of JavaScript, I reckon.

Comment: For further reference: [CSS Image Orientation Lands in Firefox 26](http://sethfowler.org/blog/2013/09/13/new-in-firefox-26-css-image-orientation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it will fit (code taken from first draft of answer) :

```
.VerticalAlign {
height: 300px;
}

.rotate90 {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform-origin: top center;
transform-origin: top center;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-50%);
transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dxweu9v5/

If the intention is to let the parent adapt to the rotated size, that is not possible without JavaScript :

[Rotated elements in CSS that affects their parent's height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16301625/3168107)

Comment: Ok, I'll take the words "`that is not possible without JavaScript`" as **answer**, as it being pointed from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affects-their-parents-height-correctly/16302202#16302202).

Comment: Cheers for following up, wish there were a better solution though. Transforms being taken out of document flow is great for animation performance but not very convenient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `overflow: auto` to the containing `div`.

```css
.rotate90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div style='border:1px solid red; margin-top:100px'>
  DIV 1
</div>
<div style='border:1px solid red;overflow: auto'>
  An
  <img class='rotate90' src="http://www.outreachaz.com/images/EMD%20Check.jpg" />image!
</div>
<div style='width:100%; border:1px solid red;'>
  DIV 2
</div>
```

Comment: ic, but I'd like to see the whole cheque image without the scroll bar if possible :)