# image rotation design by css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to rotate an image by css and javascript. I do not have much knowledge in css. I have tried by `transform`.
my css :

```
.rotate-90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wo6mos9r/5/) before applying rotating css.

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wo6mos9r/4/) after applying css.

I want output like this [attachment](https://www.flickr.com/photos/133576321@N06/19177531431/in/dateposted-public/)

**EDIT:**

For more clear insight Image rotation is working fine. I am having problem in css. When i am adding css class it is overlaping top buttons. I need to rotate and adjust image in a way that image never overlap my buttons and my page footer.

Can anyone suggest me how can I adjust image that after rotating it will adjust his position and will not overlap top buttons or footer design?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what do you want. Your rotate seems to work, no ?  You want to rotate the image when we click on "rotate" ?

Comment: I don't see any difference with the image's rotation between the first and the desired result

Comment: Hello guys sorry for the late reply. Actually my rotation is working. I have problem in css. When i am adding css class it is overlaping top buttons. I am editing my question.

Comment: I think i solved it :http://jsfiddle.net/wo6mos9r/8/ .. needed more test to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering it because someone can get help from this answer.

After some research and help from SO great users I have found solution of this issue.

**Solution:**

I needed to `translateY(-100%)`  with transform origin and needed to set min height and width to image container div.

```
.rotate-90 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

After loading image I have set min height and width by js:

```
$("#single_image .cropBox img").load(function() {
     $("#single_image").css("minWidth", this.getBoundingClientRect().width)
     $("#single_image").css("minHeight", this.getBoundingClientRect().height)
   });
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wo6mos9r/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by giving the image an id:

```
<img id="image" alt="Web_ileana-d-cruz" class="" src="https://photochute-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event_image/image/108/web_ileana-d-cruz.jpg?c=1435318866">
```

Now just grab both the image and the rotate button by id and add an event listener to the rotate button:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");

var rotateButton = document.getElementById("rotate_image_button");
rotateButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(image.className === "rotate-90") {
        image.className = "";
    } else {
        image.className = "rotate-90";
    }

    return false;
});
```

And that's it.
Basically on click you check whether or not the image has the rotated class and then just add/remove it.

This is even simpler if you use jquery. If the image can have more than just 1 class then you would need to use:

```
if((image.className+" ").indexOf("rotate-90 ") !== -1) {
    image.className = (image.className+" ").replace("rotate-90 ", "");
} else {
    if(image.className) {
        image.className += " rotate-90";
    } else {
        image.className = "rotate-90";
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wo6mos9r/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i actually already done what you have answered. My problem was after rotating image it was break design. It was overlap my buttons. Can you suggest me how can i adjust image that after rotating it will adjust his position and will not overlap top buttons or footer?

Comment: It doesn't break on my browser (chrome). You might have to translate the rotated image and set the transform origin (or fix the image container to a set height)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the first answer;

If you want the rotation to be animated aswell, you need to add this bit of CSS;

```
img {
   transition: rotate 0.5s ease; 
}
```

Please note that you will need browser prefix to make it work in all CSS3 browsers.

**Update**

With more info from the user, this problem seems to be a duplicate of [Rotated elements in CSS that affects their parent's height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affects-their-parents-height-correctly)

Comment: Thanks. I do not need to animation. My problem was after rotating image it was break design. It was overlap my buttons. Can you suggest me how can i adjust image that after rotating it will adjust his position and will not overlap top buttons or footer?

Comment: I understand, and I have created a fiddle that reproduces the problem I think you are having. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de1g6s7a/). Is this it?