# Vertical table headers in html

Tags: css, html, alignment, html-table

Consider the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test of table</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {text-align:justify;}
            li {text-align:justify;}
            ins {background-color:#A0FFA0;}
            del {background-color:#FFA0A0;}
            .code {background-color:#EEEEEE;}
            .codex {background-color:#FFFFE0;}
            .custom-table {
                text-align:center;
                font-family:monospace;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" class="custom-table">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First column</th>
                <th>Second column</th>
                <th>Third column</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First row</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second row</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third row</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like the `First column`, `Second column`, `Third column` (or in other words, all the `th` elements of the `custom-table`) texts to be non-bold, vertically written (+90° rotation counter-clockwise), vertically centered and horizontally centered within header cells. How to do that by modifying this document?

Note: I don't need backward compatibility with non-html5 browsers, I don't want javascript, and I don't want an external CSS.

Here is an example of the kind of alignment I want:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `transform: rotate`.

Comment: @RichardHamilton I know. But this html is not for a website. I am writing an official document for a committee, and they want html file format (and no external file).

Comment: @RichardHamilton I just uploaded a picture

Comment: there is a good solution here if it's still relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406895/5210321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Just found out you wanted it rotated counter-colockwise. In that case use `-90deg`

To have text vertically written, you can use the `transform: rotate(-90deg)` property. The default font-weight for `th` elements is bold, so we need to override that, making the font-weight normal.

You should be able to get away with just transform, but depending on the browser, you might need to include vendor prefixes.
This should be what you're looking for

```html
<head>
  <style>
    /* Generally, you should put CSS in a separate file, but for the purpose of this post, I'm including it in the style tag. */
    p, li { text-align: justify; }
    ins { background-color: #A0FFA0; }
    del { background-color: #FFA0A0; }
    .code { background-color: #EEEEEE; }
    .codex { background-color: #FFFFE0; }
    
    .custom-table {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: monospace;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    
    th {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      width: 95px;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    td, th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    /* Can't eliminate the spacing no matter what I try */
    th:first-child {
      height: 100px;
    }
    th:not(:first-child) {
      height: 10px;
    }
    
    td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(4) {
      width: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="custom-table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>First column</th>
      <th>Second column</th>
      <th>Third column</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First row</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second row</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third row</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Edit: Got it to look more like the screenshot, but couldn't figure out how to change the width of the cells. Looks like this is the best I can do for now

Comment: How to have the correct borders? How to have the correct cell width (same behaviour as for the horizontal ones)?

Comment: You can eliminate the width of the header by wrapping the text in an element inside the `th`, and setting `position: absolute` on it.

Comment: Downside of this solution is when you're increasing `<th>` content to a certain extent, it will break the table layout.

Comment: Why is this still so effing hard?

Answer (score 0):

To make the `th` non bold change them to standard `td`

for counter clockwise rotation

```
td.class-given-to-old-ths{

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
th {writing-mode:vertical-rl; transform:rotate(180deg)}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr><th>COL A</th><th>COL B</th><th>COL C</th></tr>
    <tr><td>001</td><td>002</td><td>003</td></tr>
    <tr><td>101</td><td>102</td><td>103</td></tr>
    <tr><td>201</td><td>202</td><td>203</td></tr>
</table>
```

**RESULTS:**

[image: results image]

**COMMENTARY:**
This method retains background shading, etc.
Simple. Quick. Easy.