# Chrome does not support "writing-mode" for BUTTON tag?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just discovered a possible bug in Chrome but I am unable to find any resource.

It seems that `writing-mode` does not run on `BUTTON` tag.

See the [living example](https://jsfiddle.net/t6d8688t/) for details.

```
<a href="#;" class="pippo">pippo</a>
<br><br>
<button class="pippo">pippo</button>

.pippo {
  writing-mode:vertical-lr
}
```

Is there any workaround to fix it in Chrome (in Firefox runs correctly)?

Answer (score 13):

You can try this:

```
<button><p style="writing-mode:vertical-lr;">pippo</p></button>
```

Comment: This could be effectively a great workaround, also with a simple `span`

Comment: you are ultra legend!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the SVG text elements.

[more info](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html)

```
<svg width="100" height="600">
    <text x="28" y="150" transform="rotate(-90, 28, 150)" style="text-anchor:middle; font-size:12px">Its vertical now</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: well, if I have to change from BUTTON to SVG, I can simply change to an A HREF, that solves the problem.... :-) My question is about a workaround to enable writing-mode for button tag, not changing completely markup

Comment: my understanding is the writing-mode is designed to change the layout and the direction of the text elements when you apply it to other classes like button, text isn't the only element being manipulated anymore. so maybe its not suppose to work flawlessly?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, 'writing-mode' only seems to work when using Internet Explorer?

It gets worse when trying to add css transforms to fix it as Internet Explorer applies both.

I needed to use the specific CSS rules for Firefox and Chrome to only use transform while IE uses writing-mode.

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 255% 55% 0;
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform-origin: 255% 55% 0;
-ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
```

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/css3-transform-only-in-firefox/

Comment: Yes, sure, other browsers needs vendor prefix, but they run correctly when using them...