# CSS Transform - Image Rotate overlapping other divs

Tags: html, css

I am rotating an image using a CSS transform like this...

https://jsfiddle.net/7ed1aqrt/

```css
.content1{background:teal;}
.imagecontainer{text-align:center;background:wheat;width:100%;}
img{transform: rotate(90deg);}
.content2{background:pink;}
```

```html
<div class ="content1">Content 1</div>

<div class ="imagecontainer">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>

<div class ="content2">Content 2</div>
```

But the rotated image is breaking out of it's container and overlapping the divs above and below it.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotated elements in CSS that affects their parent's height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affects-their-parents-height-correctly)

Comment: There are numerous posts on the subject and always the problem that after rotation the image runs out of the parent frame. I have a completely new approach: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867985/2320007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867985/2320007), using scale. (0.8 is ok, but if your image has a different ratio you can recalculate it based on height/width).

Answer (score 2):

Just try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your image container. When rotating an image that has different widths/height then you will need to offset it with a margin. See the updated answer below:

**Updated answer**

```css
.content1 { 
    background: teal;
}
           
.imagecontainer {
    text-align: center;
    background: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent overflowing of nested elements */
}

img {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin: 50px auto; /* account for 100px width/height difference */
}

.content2 {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">Content 1</div>

<div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff">
</div>

<div class="content2">Content 2</div>
```

Comment: But that cuts off the image, I still want to see the whole image

Comment: Does your updated answer rely on knowing the dimensions beforehand?

Comment: Yes it does rely on it. There is no way to do it for dynamic images without introducing some JavaScript or using an inline style when rendering the image element.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will look at using Javascript to handle things dynamically  Seems like a good choice

Comment: No worries. Just do something like get image height and width. Get the difference and then apply a margin top and bottom to the image equal to half of the calculated difference. Let me know if you need any additional assistance with it. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just added padding to the image and it stopped overlapping. Try adding this code to the `.image-container` class

```
.image-container{
   padding : 20px;
}
```

I don't think it's the perfect solution, but it helps.