# Resize Table Cell/Row to fit newly rotated image

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, rotation

https://jsfiddle.net/3tanm7yu/2/

I currently have images inside a TABLE. I can successfully rotate my images using JavaScript, but unfortunately when the landscape images become portrait the images then appear over the table lines, rather than being contained within the original cell size, or even better, adjusting the size of the table to fit the new orientation of the image.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <STYLE>
    .north {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
    }

    .west {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
    }

    .south {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
    }

    .east {
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
    }

    table {
      border: thin solid black;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
    }
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <h1>testing rotate</H1>
  <TABLE>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <IMG WIDTH=1 6 SRC='rotate.png' onclick="rotateImage('image0')">
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <IMG WIDTH=1 6 SRC='rotate.png' onclick="rotateImage('image1')">
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD><img class='north' id='image0' src="http://yernana.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/tickets.jpg" id="image" /></TD>
      <TD><img class='north' id='image1' src="http://yernana.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/tickets.jpg" id="image" /></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>

  <SCRIPT>
    function rotateImage(elementID) {
      alert('Rotating' + elementID);
      alert(document.getElementById(elementID).className);
      if (document.getElementById(elementID).className == "north") {
        alert('changing to west');
        document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'west';
      } else if (document.getElementById(elementID).className == 'west') {
        alert('changing to south');
        document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'south';
      } else if (document.getElementById(elementID).className == 'south') {
        alert('changing to east');
        document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'east';
      } else if (document.getElementById(elementID).className == 'east') {
        alert('changing to north');
        document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'north';
      }
    }
  </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: I'll have a look at the JSFiddle, I don't understand why. The CAPS is a style thing I learned a long time ago and haven't managed to shake it off.

Comment: I fixed the JSFiddle but I have not yet found a solution to your problem.. https://jsfiddle.net/3tanm7yu/15/

Comment: this could be helpful and might be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affects-their-parents-height-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the css using javascript, so basically when you call your rotate image function, have it adjust the size of the cell to fit the newly positioned image. 
For example:

```
document.getElementById('tdelement').style.width = "300px";
```

although I'd imagine having

```
width: auto;
```

for the cell should accomplish the same thing, but if not the javascript solution should suffice.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: No prob, nice implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript I used to fix the issue

```
function rotateImage(elementID, cellID) {
alert( 'Rotating' + elementID + "Resizing" + cellID);
alert(document.getElementById(elementID).className);

var img = document.getElementById(elementID);
var height = img.clientHeight;
var width = img.clientWidth;

alert('Height = ' + height + 'width = ' +width);

if(document.getElementById(elementID).className == "north"){
    alert('changing to west');
    document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'west';

    document.getElementById(cellID).style.height = width;
}
else if(document.getElementById(elementID).className == 'west'){
    alert('changing to south');
    document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'south';
}
else if(document.getElementById(elementID).className == 'south'){
    alert('changing to east');
    document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'east';
}
else if(document.getElementById(elementID).className =='east'){
    alert('changing to north');
    document.getElementById(elementID).className = 'north';
}
}
```