# Remove unwanted space with position sticky

Tags: css, sticky

I'm trying to use `position: sticky` on a rotated element but I get extra space at the top. Also where the sticky element has to stops (at the end of parent) it goes outside.

Notice I need to have control to choose how many pixels put between sticky element and the left window side.

Check the 2 screenshot to understand the 2 problems, and what I want to achieve.

**Problem 1: extra space at top**
[image: State 1 (default at start)]

**Problem 2: sticky element goes outside at the end of section**
[image: State 2 (at section end)]

I'm using this code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="section">

  <h1 class="section__title">STICKY</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col [ col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 ]">
        <div class="h4">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam quos illum aperiam officia provident, mollitia at, tempore atque, blanditiis sit optio esse harum officiis voluptas iusto sequi. Magni, reiciendis quidem.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.section__title {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translatex(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%; 
  margin-bottom: 0;

  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Here is a **Codepen** with the entire code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLqJGG

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem 1: extra space at top**

The stickily positioned element stays in the DOM flow - just like a `relative` positioned element does. So, hence the space there, which is occupied by the `h1.section__title` element.

**Problem 2: sticky element goes outside at the end of section**

It is because, the original height of the `h1` element is still considered there, even after rotation.

So, you need to determine the exact width of the sticky header (which then becomes the height of this element after rotation) first and then set this width value for the rotated element's height, as follows:

```cs
$section-sticky-header-height: 145px;

.section__title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;

  /* solves problem 1 */
  float: left; 

  /* solves problem 2 */
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translatex(-$section-sticky-header-height);
  height: $section-sticky-header-height;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arybWZ

---

Edit:

> The problem is that I cannot determine the exact width of the sticky header because the h1 text is variable (the client will insert that text via a CMS). Is there a way to handle this? If possible without Javascript

Got it. You can try this instead, if the height is variable:

```html
<h1 class="h1 mb-0 section__title">
  <div class="rotation-outer">
    <div class="rotation-inner">
      <div class="rotation">
        STICKY
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

```css
.section__title {
  border: 1px solid; // for demo purpose
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  float: left;

  .rotation-outer {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;

    .rotation-inner {
      padding: 50% 0;
      height: 0;

      .rotation {
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%);
        margin-top: -50%;
        white-space: nowrap; 
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

See in action: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BedREm

There's a very good explanation here for how this works: [Rotated elements in CSS that affect their parent's height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affect-their-parents-height-correctly/16302202#47860039)

---

Edit 2:

> At that link I also discovered the `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` property (in this answer stackoverflow.com/a/50406895/1252920). Do you think could be a better solution? I applied it in this Codepen: codepen.io/anon/pen/JqyJWK?editors=1100 What do you think?

Yes, another sweet alternative, you can use. :)

Here I changed/optimized it a little bit: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGXPPe?editors=1100

However, please note that `vertical-lr` or `vertical-rl` is not widely supported. Apparently only on **desktop** version of Chrome/Firefox/Opera. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode).
So, it's up to you, which one to use. Personally, I wouldn't use `writing-mode` due to lack of browser support.

Comment: Ok, we're almost there. The problem is that I cannot determine the exact width of the sticky header because the h1 text is variable (the client will insert that text via a CMS). Is there a way to handle this? If possible without Javascript (but if there isn't other solution we'll consider it)

Comment: Oh man, what you did is pure witchcraft! I understand it only in part. Thanks. Just one thing: I noticed that the `margin-left` on `.section__title` moves the `.container`, while it should remains independent from sticky element. Is it possible?

Comment: Huh, sorry about that. I updated my answer. Removed margin-left. Added `position: relative; left: 50px` to  `.rotation-outer`. It should do it.

Comment: @FredK Please see the link I added for a detailed explanation. :)

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thanks so much! At that link I also discovered the `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` property (in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406895/1252920). Do you think could be a better solution? I applied it in this Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqyJWK?editors=1100 What do you think?

Comment: @FredK Thanks for the feedback. You can find my answer in the post - updated.

Comment: About `vertical-rl` support I looked here https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode and it actually seems supported by all except IE browsers. So I'm pretty confused, since your link from Mozilla says the opposite! Instead, about the first method, he says https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860039/1252920 that is not fully spec-compliant so it may be no longer supported in the future. Thinking about what is more secure...

Comment: @FredK Unfortunately, I never used/needed `writing-mode` CSS property before. Thus, I can only recommend you to test it with multiple browsers (both desktop and mobile browsers). [Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/writing-mode/) in the `Browser support` section it looks also promising. If you are happy with the test results, go for it! Otherwise I see no reason, why you shouldn't try the previous solution, since it also works too.