# Why is there a weird space in my sticky table header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add `position: sticky; top: 0` to the `<thead>` element of my table, the `<thead>` has this weird gap I can't get rid of between itself & the top of the table element.

[Pic of the weird space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWRbu.png)

EDIT: Also happens on Safari@16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12) but instead of the weird gap being at the top of the thead, its at the bottom (see pic): [Weird gap viewed on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuIyj.png)

For context this is run via a nextjs@14.0.4 project, accessed via Chrome (Version 120.0.6099.109 Official Build - arm64) on an M1 Mac running Ventura 13.0.1

For context, here are the styles I apply to my table (but the problem goes away if I remove the position: sticky - can't figure out how to make it go away while still having the header stick / if anyone has any context on this):

```css
/* article table styling: */

.disc-story-article figure.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  max-width: 98%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0.22rem solid var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}


/* article table overall styling */

.disc-story-article figure.table table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* article table caption styling */

.disc-story-article figure.table figcaption {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}


/* THIS !! article table header styling: */

.disc-story-article table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* article table header row styling: */

.disc-story-article table thead tr {
  color: var(--background);
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}


/* article table right-most column cell styling */

.disc-story-article table tr td:nth-last-child(1),
.disc-story-article table tr th:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-right-width: 0 !important;
}


/* article table bottom-most row cell styling */

.disc-story-article table tr:nth-last-child(1) td {
  border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
}


/* article table general cell styling: */

.disc-story-article table td,
.disc-story-article table th {
  border-top: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  border-right: 0.12rem solid var(--primary-color) !important;
  border-bottom: 0.12rem solid var(--primary-color) !important;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<figure class="table" style="float: right;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="border: 5px double rgb(77, 230, 77);">outlined cell</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="background-color: rgb(230, 77, 77);">background</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">cent</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px;">5pad</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 55px; width: 45px;">45x55</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</figure>
```

Tried playing with margin/padding/border etc... to no avail. Also tried messing with transform/translates to see if it would go away (e.g. [Remove unwanted space with position sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200160/remove-unwanted-space-with-position-sticky)) Doesn't seem to be a super publicized problem on Google/SO or maybe I'm just missing it

Comment: the code you present is incomplete and does not allow you to verify what you are saying, nor to be able to experiment/search for an answer...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0):

This Answer may be helpful for you how table display and table border etc. see output of this code for better understanding... Try Table with border

```css
*{
padding="0px";
margin="0px";

}


/* article table styling: */

.disc-story-article figure.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  max-width: 98%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0.22rem solid var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}


/* article table overall styling */

.disc-story-article figure.table table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* article table caption styling */

.disc-story-article figure.table figcaption {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}


/* THIS !! article table header styling: */

.disc-story-article table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* article table header row styling: */

.disc-story-article table thead tr {
  color: var(--background);
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}


/* article table right-most column cell styling */

.disc-story-article table tr td:nth-last-child(1),
.disc-story-article table tr th:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-right-width: 0 !important;
}


/* article table bottom-most row cell styling */

.disc-story-article table tr:nth-last-child(1) td {
  border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
}


/* article table general cell styling: */

.disc-story-article table td,
.disc-story-article table th {
  border-top: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  border-right: 0.12rem solid var(--primary-color) !important;
  border-bottom: 0.12rem solid var(--primary-color) !important;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<figure class="table" style="float: right;">
  <table border="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="border: 5px double rgb(77, 230, 77);">outlined cell</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="background-color: rgb(230, 77, 77);">background</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">cent</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px;">5pad</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 55px; width: 45px;">45x55</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</figure>
```