# flexbox items covers others after applying rotate transform

Tags: css

I think it's faster to describe my question in images.

[image: What I made and what I expect]

- I have some flex rectangle cards and a flex container.
- I applied `rotate(90deg)` to one of the cards, the cards are 1:2 so I was expecting the other cards would be pushed left and right, which did not happen
- I applied `align-items: flex-end;` to the flex container, because I wanted the card to "touch the ground" after rotating, which did not happen either

What should I do to make that 2 effects ;(

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <div id="card"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div id="card"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item spin">
        <div id="card"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div id="card"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
#card {
  border: 8px black solid;
  aspect-ratio: 1/2;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.spin {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-pine-0ucjo3

Comment: Please add you code to the question body as text / stack snippet and not in an external site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotated elements in CSS that affect their parent's height correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301625/rotated-elements-in-css-that-affect-their-parents-height-correctly)

Comment: adding margin is not what you needed, `.spin {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin: 0 30px;
}`

Comment: When you are putting your code into your question perhaps you could take the opportunity to put it through a validator. It has many elements with the same id which is not valid HTML.